# How to ask permission for geolocation every time?

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation

I would like to be asked every time for the permission to access to geolocation.
How to do that?
I thought to revoke the permission everytime and then ask it for again, but that doesn't work. According to documentation it has been deprecated.

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state === 'granted') {
   //to do things here 
  
  } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
   //ask for permission
  
  } else if(result.state === 'denied'){
   //keep asking for permission
  
  }
  report(result.state);
});
```

/////

```
  if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      console.log('there is geolocation')
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((success) => {
        console.log('success geo', success.coords)
        
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error, 'error')
      }, { maximumAge: 0});

    } else{
      alert('Please grant access to location')
    }
  }
```

From what I have been reading, it seems that once the user has given access to location, the browser remembers. That's why I added also maximumAge; I thought that adding that, I could have a mechanism to allow to ask for the geolocation permission every time the user loads a page.

Comment: Can I ask why??

Comment: This can't be done ... but why do you need to do that

Comment: @Adam, I needed to have this implementation. So once the user grants permission to the browser to access to location, this can't be changed. And if the user denies it, the user has to go manually and change its own settings, correct?

Comment: @user7445842547 yes this is it

Comment: @Adam, do you know if there are other api I can use?

Comment: @user7445842547 bro .. there is no way to do that ... JavaScript cannot control the browser ... but why do you need to do that ? .. I may be able to help you

Comment: @Adam, I am building this application where when the user clicks a button, a new page is opened. and there is a button inside where the user should share its own location. and i would like to ask the permission every time to do that.

Comment: So you need to update its location every time that button is pressed

Comment: @Adam. No I want to that the user is asked to give permission to use the location